# Get item from list through for-loop

Tags: c#, linq, list, for-loop, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get the name of several projects of several partners and I miss something maybe.

Here is the script

So that's code for the List.

```
// JSON ---------------------------------------------
[System.Serializable]
public struct MyClassList
{   
    [System.Serializable]
    public struct Partner
    {
        public int partner_id;
        public string partner_name;
        public string _partner_logo_ressource_link;
    }

    public List<Partner> partner;

    [System.Serializable]
    public struct Project
    {
        public int project_id;
        public string project_name;
        public string partner_partner_name;
        public string type_type_name;
    }

    public List<Project> project;

    public static MyClassList CreateFromJSON(string jsonString)
        {
            return JsonUtility.FromJson<MyClassList>(jsonString);
        }
}
// --------------------------------------------------
```

And here is how i m trying to get the value.

```
void InstantieMenuPartner()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < _partnerList.partner.Count; i++)
    {
        GameObject _instance_partner_menu = Instantiate(_prefab_menu_project);
        _instance_partner_menu.name = "Menu_Partner_"+_partnerList.partner[i].partner_name;

        _instance_partner_menu.transform.SetParent(GameObject.Find("Menu_Project").transform, false);

        // Instantie Button Project to Parent Menu Partner -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        for(int p = 0; p < _projectList.project.Count(a => a.partner_partner_name == _partnerList.partner[i].partner_name); p++)
        {
            GameObject _instance_project_button = Instantiate(_prefab_button_project);

            Debug.Log(_projectList.project.Where(a => (a.partner_partner_name == _partnerList.partner[i].partner_name) && (a.project_name == _projectList.project[p].project_name)).Select(a => a.project_name).FirstOrDefault());

            _instance_project_button.transform.SetParent(GameObject.Find("Menu_Partner_"+_partnerList.partner[i].partner_name).transform, false);

            //Text _instance_project_button_text = _instance_project_button.GetComponentInChildren<Text>();
            //_instance_project_button_text.text = _projectList.project[p].project_name;
        }
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------      
        _instance_partner_menu.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

The Debug.Log part is where I get a issue.

To Explain, I have a List full of partner in a database and each partner have several project.

Through the loop, I'm trying to Instantie a GameObject for the partner and set projects as children of this GameObject.

But I can't make it work.

Comment: Try avoid Linq in Unity, it is slower and memory consuming when done in Update and sometimes not working on some platform like iOS. Try to redo the method with your own code.

Comment: Thanks for the Advice ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I get it.

Replace the Debug.Log part by:

```
Debug.Log(_projectList.project
    .Where(a => a.partner_partner_name == _partnerList.partner[i].partner_name)
    .Select(c => c.project_name)
    .ElementAtOrDefault(p));
```

So with only one condition you get the list of the partner and then I select in the list the good variable and with ElementAt I get my value.